# adding a timer for a power up in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a car based discord bot and I want to add power ups , one of them include Nitrous . Nitrous will increase your power for 30 minutes and then revert back to normal but for some reason it forgets the timer and permanently increases the user's power. I tried using `await asyncio.sleep(1800)` but it doesn't seem to work as you can see (1800 seconds is 30 minutes) . No errors are shown too.

This is the code...

```
@client.command()
async def use(ctx, option = None):

    global nit

    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    car = users[str(user.id)]["car"]

    hp = users[str(user.id)]["hp"]
    hpn = hp*1.5

    nos = users[str(user.id)]["nit"]


    if option == None:
        await ctx.send('You forgot to type an option!')

    elif option == 'nos' or option == 'Nitrous':
        if nit == True:
            await ctx.send('Nitrous is already enabled!')
            return

        if nos>0:
            await ctx.send('Are you sure you want to enable it? This will increase your HP by 50 percent for 30min, Type Y or N')
            msg = await client.wait_for('message',timeout = 20.0, check=lambda message: not message.author.bot)
            if msg.content.lower() == 'y' or msg.content.lower() == 'Y':
                await change_bank(ctx.author, "nitn", car)
                await change_bank(ctx.author, "nithp", hp)
                await change_bank(ctx.author, "hp", hpn)
                await update_bank(ctx.author, -1, "nit")

                nit = True

                await ctx.send('You have used Nitrous , your timer will start now!')

                await asyncio.sleep(1800)

                user = ctx.author

                users = await get_bank_data()

                car = users[str(user.id)]["car"]
                carn = users[str(user.id)]["nitn"]
                hp = users[str(user.id)]["nithp"]
                nit = False

                if carn == car:
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "hp", hp)
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "nithp", 0)
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "nitn", 0)
                    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}'s 30min of Nitrous is finish!")
                else:
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "hp2", hp)
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "nithp", 0)
                    await change_bank(ctx.author, "nitn", 0)
                    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}'s 30min of Nitrous is finish!")
            else:
                await ctx.send('Either you chose "N" or you didnt type in time!')
        else:
            await ctx.send('You dont have enough nitrous bottles!')
```

Comment: `asyncio.sleep` blocks the execution of a certain function,(pretty much the name speaks for itself, it's ***sleeping***, not waiting) that's not exactly what you want...

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński what command is more suitable?

Comment: There's no such "command". My suggestion: Have a variable that holds the users that have the nitro activated and the time when it started, in the command check if the user has one, and check if it still can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have discovered one of the big issues involved with using any sort of sleep function to manage future events. The way `asyncio.sleep` works is that it registers a future. A future is like a placeholder for a function that hasn't returned yet. You don't have to wait for the function until you actually want to read the result but the function is still processing in the background. Futures are one of the foundational elements of asynchronous processing.

Technically `asyncio.sleep` should work in this context. I'm not sure entirely what is happening but most likely the `discord.py` library has some sort of manager that drops these futures if they're suspended for more than a certain amount of time. If I find out more about this then I'll edit this answer.

The long and the short of it is that you should not use sleep calls for long events like this one. Instead, you should create a global (or guild-level) database and have a looping task that reads from that database and calls a function that runs all the code below the `asyncio.sleep`. You could do this by creating a dictionary that stores when a users nitro will finish along with some other information like the author and channel.

You can find out more about tasks in the discord.py library [**here**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)